# Safe disconnect of GPIO in raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gpio

When writing 'C' code for the raspberry pi and its GPIO pins, then shutting down that program, sometimes and LED will stay or - leading me to believe that there may be things going on that i'm missing

*How would I let all of the memory go and disconnect the GPIO pin which i  have defined as an output when 'kill' is call or ctrl+c is press?*

Although i'm not new to coding, i'm new to the pi, so any solution would be great!

-H

Comment: This should be about properly handling *signals*...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this question actually isn't very Raspberry-specific:

You can switch off the LEDs in a signal handler catching SIGINT or other signals ending your process or in an `atexit()` (for "normal exits") routine.

In case your process is killed with a SIGKILL or SIGSTOP signal, though, you cannot do anything as a dying gasp action as those signals cannot be caught.

Comment: when you say "normal exits", what does that constitute, and how would that occur?

Comment: A "normal exit" in my terminology is an `exit()` call or a `return` from `main()`